# Question on independent events in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The "on" temperature of thermostatically controlled switch for an air conditioning system is set at $60$ degrees, but the actual temperature X at which the switch turns on is a random variable having pdf:

$$f_X(x) = \begin{cases}1/2  &    71^\circ\leqslant x\leqslant 73^\circ 
\\0 & \text{ elsewhere }\end{cases}$$

(a) Find the probability that a temperature in excess of $72^\circ$ is required to turn the switch on.

(b) If two switches are used independently , find the probability that both require a temperature in excess of $72^\circ$ to turn on.

My understanding of this question: 
for a single switch probability is integration of $f_X(x)$ from $72$ to infinity
That gives the answer to part a that comes out to be $1/2$

For part two I am having doubt. 
For independent events $P(AB) = P(A) * P(B) = 1/2 * 1/2 = 1/4$.

Is there any mistake in my understanding of the concept.

I am preparing for my exams so please if you give me a better insight to the problem that would be really appreciable. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.   The probability that a uniformly distributed random variable is realised in the upper half of its support is $1/2$.   The probability of two independent such variables both do so is $1/4$.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X_\ast\geq 72^\circ) & = \int_{72}^{73} \tfrac 1 2 \operatorname d t \\[1ex] &= \tfrac 1 2
\\[2ex] \mathsf P(X_1\geq 72^\circ, X_2\geq 72^\circ) & \mathop{=}^{\text{ind}} \mathsf P(X_\ast\geq 72^\circ)^2 \\[1ex] & = \tfrac 1 4
\end{align}$$

---

**Remark:**  This is the probability that both switches require a temperature in excess of $72^\circ$ to turn on.   We would get a different answer if we were looking the probability that a temperature in excess of $72^\circ$ is required to turn on both switches.

$$\begin{align} \mathsf P(X_1\geq 72^\circ \cup X_2\geq 72^\circ) & = 2 \mathsf P(X_\ast\geq 72^\circ) - \mathsf P(X_\ast\geq 72^\circ)^2 \\[1ex] & = \tfrac 3 4
\end{align}$$